# Correlate an Inapp transaction with the Financial report

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am working with the Inapp purchases in my current app.
After successfull purchase i save the "receipt" of the product on my server.
I am aware about the "Financial Reports" provided on iTunes Connect at monthly intervals.
Now my question is what should i have to do to validate a particular transaction with the Financial report provided by apple.
I see some sample Financial reports but couldn't find any such parameter which give the transaction Id or any other unique field.

Also, if there is any way of attaching some payload during the Payment request and get that payload back in the receipt and the Financial report?. This might solve the problem from me.

Comment: So here you want to map your purchases/receipt with the Financial report provided by Apple ?

Comment: @AjaySharma: Yes Ajay. In my case, if my app user query me about a particular payment then i want it to validate directly with the Financial report of iTunes connect because at the end all the transaction of the app get listed there.